# Weird behaviour in a for loop changing the results

Tags: c++

i've got a weird problem in my code.
here's the context : in my method i create an object and then i fill the (int) buffer of this object with data in TWO "for loops".

The problem is , when i insert a printf in my loop to look at the data into my buffer, it change the data in the buffer.
actually, the result in the buffer is different if there's a printf inside the loop or not

Heres's my code, maybe it can help to understand :

```
bool Mod::Realiser(FFTResult * inputdata,FFTSample_s * & moduleData){
bool done = true;
float module;
unsigned int r,n;
moduleData = new FFTSample_s(NbPointsSample);
    unsigned int limit = NbPointsSample >> 1;
int iGain= 0;

  for (n = CentrageFFT, r = 0; r < limit; n++, r++)
  {

   module = inputdata->buffer[n][0] * inputdata->buffer[n][0] + inputdata->buffer[n][1] * inputdata->buffer[n][1];
    //  printf(" M = %lf\n",module);
   moduleData->buffer[r] = (int)(10.0*log10(module)) + iGain;

  }


  for (n = 0; n < limit; n++, r++)
  {

   module = inputdata->buffer[n][0] * inputdata->buffer[n][0] + inputdata->buffer[n][1] * inputdata->buffer[n][1];
   moduleData->buffer[r] = (int)(10.0*log10(module)) + iGain;


  }
 /* for (int i=0;i<2048;i++){
      printf(" X =  %lf \n",inputdata->buffer[i][0]);
      printf(" Y =  %lf \n",inputdata->buffer[i][1]);
      printf(" M = %d\n",moduleData->buffer[i]);
  }*/
```

Comment: That sounds like an overflow problem of some sort.

Comment: You do know what the `"%lf"` format in [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) means? That means it want to print a `double` but you provide a `float`. Why don't you use the type-safe `std::cout` for output?

Comment: Try using valgrind. Without knowing most of the types involved and their contents (e.g. we don't even know what this buffer variable is you talk about) and how they came to life, we can't do anything but guess.

Comment: yeah that's true , i don't why i keep using printf in c++ , i'll try to use std::cout

Comment: i know , it was hard to show you the all framework

Comment: Is `r` supposed to be reset to zero before the second loop?

Comment: no , r has the good value in the second loop but i think @David gave me the anwser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior. See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). By passing a floating point number to `printf`, you probably force the implementation to convert it into canonical `float` form from an internal form that happens to have higher precision.

The results can be different. There is not one and only one right answer.

Also:

> "The result of a + b is stored in a temporary destination of unspecified precision. Neither the C++ or IEEE standards mandate what precision intermediate calculations are done to and this intermediate precision will affect your results. The temporary result could equally easily be stored in a float or a double and there are significant advantages to both options. " - [Floating-Point Determinism](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/)